# Multiple listboxes scroll at same time?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 listboxes and I want to scroll one meanwhile others also are scrolling. I can scroll by mousewheel and drag scrollbar.

Comment: Maybe you can create your own UserControl based on a ListBox. Using template make it *look like* 3 listboxes even if *it is not*

Comment: I asked same question here. You can read it to find out 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167306/first-listbox-scrollbar-movement-should-effect-second-listbox-scrollbar-movement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

[Two listbox scrollbar in synchronisation](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/38413d0a-7388-4191-a7a6-fd66e469d502)

Comment: Thank for your "Here you go".

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this article](http://cromwellhaus.com/2009/03/scrolling-multiple-content-areas-with-a-single-scrollbar-in-wpf/). It shows how this can be done by using binding and `RenderTransform`.

Another thing you might want to check is the [`ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollchanged.aspx). You can possibly listen to this event and set the scrolling for your listboxes as necessary.